# Google map INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, installation, android-mapview

I  gets error :Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
when I want to install my code to my moto xt316 Phone.

and I have try：
set the target Google apis 2.3 or 2.2

and my code install and run ok in others phone （defy，g6）

if I remove

It can install in the moto xt316, but as we know , it can not use mapView if I remove it.

And the xt316 has not installed google map.

Can I try to install to xt316 with  
but not get Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY.
Because I want my code can install in all Phone!

Comment: So did I get your goal right, you're trying to use Google Maps API on a phone that does not have Google Maps application installed?

Answer (score 1):

> And the xt316 has not installed google map.

Then you cannot use an application that requires the Google Maps add-on for Android.

> Because I want my code can install in all Phone!

Then you cannot require the Google Maps add-on for Android.

What you *can* do is make the Google Maps add-on for Android optional, by adding `android:required="false"` to the `<uses-library>` element in your manifest. Then, at runtime, you can use `Class.forName()` to see if `MapActivity` is available, and set up your UI from there. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkMapless) that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

Using latest version of Rhomobile 3.3.3+ and started seeing this error?  Go to your build.yml and look for the "non motorola device" option and try checking that off and then rebuilding your app.